# Home url function not working correctly in plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have an issue that when i'm calling `home_url($wp->request)` in themes page or functions.php it works correctly, the out put is : http://localhost/WP_CUSTOM/tester , but when i'm calling in plugin the output is not correct : http://localhost/WP_CUSTOM .

This is i tried so far.

```
function init(){
    global $wp;
    $current_url =  home_url( $wp->request );
    print_r($current_url);
}
add_action('init','init');
```

I write these code in functions.php file of my plugin

Comment: You should generally use `get_home_url()` for variables in plugins. also -  what is the reason you are using  ` $wp->request ` ? it makes the request relative and will generally display the current page if the request is available.

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on what it is that you are really trying to get.

```
global $wp;
 home_url( $wp->request );
```

will generally give you the url of current page if the request is available. it is relative. ( a bit like `get_permalink()`, but not the same )

Also, in general, while in plugins it would be advised to use the wp `get_*()` functions, or in this case, `get_home_url()`

It would be better however if you will tell us what is thee url that you are trying to get and to what purpose. there might be better ways.